# Login to wordpress using PHP and curl

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have browsed through numerous questions/answers related to php curl wordpress login but could not get any to work.

I have domainA.com with a webapp which stores a wordpress administration username and password. There is a login button which when clicked should login and redirect me to domainB.com/wp-admin on a new tab.

Using this code:

```
$username="admin";
$password="pword";
$url="http://domainB.com/";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = "log=". $username ."&pwd=". $password ."&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=". $url ."wp-admin/&wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+Check";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "/wp-login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "wp-admin/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

This works fine. I get loggedin, but my url remains http://domainA.com/webapp/index.php.
I want to be redirected to regular administration http://domainB.com/wp-admin

Next i tried:

```
$username="admin";
$password="pword";
$url="http://domainB.com/";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = "log=". $username ."&pwd=". $password ."&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=". $url ."wp-admin/&wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+Check";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "/wp-login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "wp-admin/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header('Location:'.$url.'wp-admin');
```

This does not seem to log me in.

I can not seem to find what is wrong.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the user session with the cURL session. Using cURL to log in will not authenticate the user on the end of a web browser, only the script running the command. I suggest explaining what you're trying to accomplish and maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: I am just trying to have my wp admin username and password saved on my web app. And when i click on login in my webapp.. i am actually redirected to my wordpress admin and i have already being logged in.